# Perform mash layer properties values update automatically

Tags: qgis

I would perform this two actions at project opened (by a Python macro or everything else), is possible?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

For the first one, this only works if it doesn't change the symbology (even if the color scale field doesn't work anymore):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.reload()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

I tried with this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for g in layer.datasetGroupsIndexes():
    if layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).name().startswith("Total precipitation"):
        maxVal = layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).maximum()
        minVal = layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).minimum()
        print(maxVal, " ", minVal)
        mesh_renderer = layer.rendererSettings()
        mesh_renderer.setActiveScalarDatasetGroup(g)
        scalar_settings = mesh_renderer.scalarSettings(g)
        scalar_settings.setClassificationMinimumMaximum(minVal,maxVal)
        mesh_renderer.setScalarSettings(g,scalar_settings)
        layer.setRendererSettings(mesh_renderer)
        iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Change only the maximum and minimum values...not the others

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Here is the code to insert as a project macro to update the mash layers classification (any suggestions for improvement are welcome! :-)

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import Qgis
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsMeshDatasetIndex
from qgis.core import QgsColorRampShader
from qgis.core import QgsColorRampLegendNodeSettings

def openProject():
 layers = ["Pioggia cumulata oraria 48h", "Probabilità di pioggia", "Previsioni ER COSMO 5m"]
 for layerName in layers:
  tmp = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layerName)
    if(tmp):
     layer = tmp[0]
      for g in layer.datasetGroupsIndexes(): 
       if layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).name().startswith("PREC") or layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).name().startswith("Total precipitation") :
                maxVal = layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).maximum()
                minVal = layer.datasetGroupMetadata(QgsMeshDatasetIndex(g,0)).minimum()
                meshRenderer = layer.rendererSettings()        
                scalarSettings = meshRenderer.scalarSettings(g)
                scalarSettings.setClassificationMinimumMaximum(minVal,maxVal)
                colorRampShader = scalarSettings.colorRampShader()
                newColorRampShader = QgsColorRampShader(minVal, maxVal, colorRampShader.createColorRamp(), colorRampShader.colorRampType(), colorRampShader.classificationMode())
                newColorRampShader.setLegendSettings(QgsColorRampLegendNodeSettings(colorRampShader.legendSettings()))
                newColorRampShader.classifyColorRampV2()
                scalarSettings.setColorRampShader(newColorRampShader)
                meshRenderer.setScalarSettings(g,scalarSettings)
                layer.setRendererSettings(meshRenderer)
                layer.triggerRepaint()
                iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

For the time reference update, since version 3.28 there is a new possibility that solves the problem:

[image]